# In XSLT, how can you sort using an indirect key?

Tags: xslt, attributes, sorting

I am having trouble getting `xsl:sort` to understand the scope of the attributes I am referencing. Here is an XML sample document to illustrate:

```
<Root>
  <DrinkSelections>
    <Drink id=1000 name="Coffee"/>
    <Drink id=1001 name="Water"/>
    <Drink id=1002 name="Tea"/>
    <Drink id=1003 name="Almost But Not Quite Entirely Unlike Tea"/>
  </DrinkSelections>

  <CustomerOrder>
    <Drinks>
      <Drink oid="1001"/>
      <Drink oid="1002"/>
      <Drink oid="1003"/>
    </Drinks>
  </CustomerOrder

</Root>
```

I want to produce a list of drinks (sorted by name) contained in the CustomerOrder.  Here is the XSLT code I am fiddling with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/CustomerOrder/Drinks/Drink">
   <xsl:sort select="/Root/DrinkSelections/Drink[@id = @oid]/@name"/>
   <xsl:variable name=var_oid select="@oid"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="/Root/DrinkSelections/Drink[@id = $var_oid]/@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Apparently, the `xsl:sort` command is trying to apply the "oid" attribute to the Drink elements in DrinkSelections, rather than local Drink element.

I can get around this using a variable, as in the `xsl:value-of` statement. But since `xsl:sort` must be the first statement after the `xsl:for-each` statement, I can't insert the `xsl:variable` statement before `xsl:sort`.

Is there a way to explicitly state that the attribute value should be taken from the "local" element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `current()` function.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/CustomerOrder/Drinks/Drink">
  <xsl:sort select="/Root/DrinkSelections/Drink[@id = current()/@oid]/@name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/Root/DrinkSelections/Drink[@id = current()/@oid]/@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But more prominently, you are missing XSL keys, for readability *and* performance:

```
<xsl:key name="kDrinkById" match="DrinkSelections/Drink" use="@id" />

<!-- ... later ... -->
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/CustomerOrder/Drinks/Drink">
  <xsl:sort select="key('kDrinkById', @oid)/@name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="key('kDrinkById', @oid)/@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

An you are probably not using templates right, because if you did, your `xsl:for-each` select expression would not start at the root.

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="CustomerOrder/Drinks" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomerOrder/Drinks">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Drink">
    <xsl:sort select="key('kDrinkById', @oid)/@name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomerOrder/Drinks/Drink">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('kDrinkById', @oid)/@name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I removed the for-each also. Every `xsl:for-each` avoided is a step towards better XSLT code (very rare exceptions apply).

Comment: Thanks! I figured there was some explicit reference available.

And thanks also for the approach using a key. I've only messed with keys a couple of times in my somewhat limited XSLT experience.

And yes, I do not begin for-each from the root. I was just trying to make the example more concise. My actual code uses a relative reference from within a match template.

Comment: @edholder: I thought so, but you never know. ;-) The key will speed up things greatly if you have large amounts of data to process this way.